A matplotlib is not showing the whole length of the index
I'm working with a data base that has 20 years of data. I created a function where the aim was to graph the database. The problem that I ran into is that the index of the graph isn't readable at all.
I tried to use plt.tight_layout() to make the graph readable but it didn't work. I also tried to write a marker every 300 entries but it also didn't work.
These are my functions:
def leeDatos():
    dataSet = pd.read_csv('covid.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
    dataSet.index = pd.to_datetime(dataSet.index,format='%d/%m/%y',errors='ignore')
    pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

    return dataSet

def graficaDatos(dataSet=0):

    plt.figure(figsize=(10, 7))
    for i in range(len(dataSet.columns)):
        plt.plot(dataSet.iloc[:,i],label=dataSet.columns[i],marker=i+2,markevery=1500)
    plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
    plt.title('COVID-19', fontweight='bold')
    plt.xlabel('Tiempo')
    plt.ylabel('Valor')
    plt.legend(loc='upper left')
    plt.tight_layout()  # Ajusta la disposición para evitar el solapamiento
    plt.show()

I tried to run the code both in collab and in vscode to change the enviroment
Unreadable index:

Found a solution in a similar question where I added this lines of code
ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_xticks(ax.get_xticks()[::100])

This worked because it made the index readable but now it only shows values of the first year:
enter image description here
